# Is there any way I can check my .json key works without importing the wallet?

Tags: wallets

Could I do this on an offline machine perhaps? I'd like to double check my key works without exposing myself to technical mess ups that would lead me to losing all my ether.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MyEtherWallet.

The online version is available at https://www.myetherwallet.com/ .

To use the offline version:

- Download the source code from https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet
- Copy the code to your offline machine
- Unzip the code
- Use a browser to open index.html
- Use the View Wallet Info page to confirm that your .json key works.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking about the existence of hardware wallets. I looked at the top few btc hardware wallets (trezor, ledger, etc) and none of them yet offer ETH support.

I think the demand for this will be high so it is likely to come at some point although it has not yet arrived.